# Get path of the file to execute from received http request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a backend app to receive .jar file from the client and run it. Following is the client code.

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let file = document.getElementById("filePath").files[0];
    formData.append("jarFile", file);
    req.open("POST", '/deployArtifact');
    req.send(formData);
```

I need to write the backend endpoint(Node Red) to get this file and run it. Following is the sketch of the nodejs post endpoint code.

```
    RED.httpAdmin.post("/deployArtifact", RED.auth.needsPermission('MyNode.read'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req);
    cmd.get(
            'java -jar ' + xxxx,
            function (err, data, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json(err);
                } else {
                    res.json(data);
                }
            });
});
```

First, I need to get the file object receiving. I tried to access `req.files` but got `undefined` for it. I printed whole req. Following is the Incoming message.

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 465,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 39624,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2108,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2109,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 2108 },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 465,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 39624,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2108,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2109,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 2108 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: '127.0.0.1:1880',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
     accept: '*/*',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:1880/',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------18210612061998272948903541154',
     'content-length': '39395364',
     connection: 'keep-alive' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Host',
     '127.0.0.1:1880',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
     'Accept',
     '*/*',
     'Accept-Language',
     'en-US,en;q=0.5',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate',
     'Referer',
     'http://127.0.0.1:1880/',
     'Content-Type',
     'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------18210612061998272948903541154',
     'Content-Length',
     '39395364',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/deployArtifact',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 465,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1880',
        _webSocketPaths: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 772 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 39624,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2108,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2109,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 2108 },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/deployArtifact',
  _parsedUrl: 
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/deployArtifact',
     path: '/deployArtifact',
     href: '/deployArtifact',
     _raw: '/deployArtifact' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: 
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 465,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 39624,
        _destroyed: false,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2108,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2109,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 2108 },
     connection: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 465,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 39624,
        _destroyed: false,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2108,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2109,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 2108 },
     _header: null,
     _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
     _sent100: false,
     _expect_continue: false,
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {},
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: { 'x-powered-by': [Array] } },
  body: {},
  route: 
   Route {
     path: '/deployArtifact',
     stack: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
```

How should I get the file object from the request to run it with 'java -jar' command. According to my understanding I need to get the path of the file uploaded to the backend server. How can I get the path of the file object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much about RED. I guess your problem is generic in terms of uploading files/receiving files.

you may want to look at `multipart/form-data` while posting(uploading your file)

A very simple example is present at https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp